# Why this.contains not a function when I call it inside another function

Tags: javascript, graph

I am trying to make a Graph and implementing one method at a time. I don't know why I get after I call a.contains("cats") I get this error '//TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined'. After removing all the values. Perhaps it has to do with this.nodes.splice(i,1)?

```
var Graph = function(){
   this.nodes = [];
   this.edges = {};
};

Graph.prototype.addNode = function(node){
  this.nodes.push(node);
  this.edges[node] = {};
};

Graph.prototype.contains = function(node){
 for(var i = 0; i < this.nodes[i].length; i++){
    if(this.nodes[i] === node){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
};

Graph.prototype.removeNode = function(node){

    for(var key in this.edges){
        if(key === node){
          delete this.edges[node];
        }
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < this.nodes.length; i++){
        if(this.nodes[i] === node){
            this.nodes.splice(i,1);
        }
    }

};

var a = new Graph();
a.addNode("cats");
a.addNode("dogs");
a.contains("cats");
a.removeNode("dogs");
a.contains("cats");
a.removeNode("cats");
a.contains("cats"); //TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Comment: I think you need this.nodes.length instead of this.nodes[i].length

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.nodes[i].length; i++)
```

to

```
    for (var i = 0; i < this.nodes.length; i++)
```

Comment: Hey i fixed, but now I get undefined after I call a.contains("cats") -> undefined. It should spit out true of false, no?

Comment: If you're trying to check does nodes contains node I would suggest this way, it is cleaner and shorter: return nodes.indexOf(node) != -1, use that instead of for loop